# Rails ignoring redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to authenticate a user via oauth2 and the `google-auth-library-ruby` library to be able to perform a few task on their gmail account.

My controller looks like this:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController

  def list_email_labels
    # Initialize the API
    service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
    service.client_options.application_name = "Application Name"
    service.authorization = authorize

    # Show the user's labels
    user_id = "me"
    @labels = service.list_user_labels user_id
  end

  def authorize
    token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: "token.yaml"
    scope = Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_READONLY
    client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_hash auth_hash
    authorizer = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.new(client_id, scope, token_store, "/auth/google_oauth2/callback")
    user_id = "me"
    
    credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id, request)

    if credentials.nil?
      redirect_to authorizer.get_authorization_url(login_hint: user_id, request: request), allow_other_host: true
    end
    credentials
  end

  def callback
    target_url = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.handle_auth_callback_deferred(request)
    redirect target_url
  end

  def auth_hash
    {
      "web" => {
        "client_id" => [CLIENT_ID],
        "project_id" => [PROJECT_ID],
        "auth_uri" => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        "token_uri" => 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url" => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
        "client_secret" => [CLIENT_SECRET],
        "redirect_uris" => ['http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback']
      }
    }
  end
end
```

When I run this, I get an error `Google::Apis::AuthorizationError in ExampleController#list_email_labels`.

The error references this line:

`@labels = service.list_user_labels user_id`

in the `list_email_labels` action.

It seems that rails ignores the `redirect_to` in the `authorize` action.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `return` to make it work because it's not the end of method. Try `return (redirect_to authorizer.get_authorization_url(login_hint: user_id, request: request), allow_other_host: true)`

Comment: @Vibol Doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

statements after redirect_to in your controller gets executed. to terminate the execution immediately after redirect_to use return

```
redirect_to example_url and return
```